# CKEditor to show iframe content when content is being open for editing

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

When I add code for `iframes` dynamically into CKEditor, they get rendered as they would on the web page, and I can correctly see the contents of the web page inside the iframe. And after submitting the form, the iframe code gets successfully saved.

So I don't know why the authors of CKEditors made it so, but when I go back to editing the same article, the iframe will not get rendered; instead there is just an image with a red label that says "IFRAME".

I tried adding `config.allowedContent = true;`, 
i tried adding `config.extraAllowedContent = 'iframe[*]';`, I tried searching for a plugin that would allow for iframes to be rendered, and I've searched the documentation on http://docs.ckeditor.com, but with no success.

It is obviously possible for CKEditor to render it and still function correctly and submit valid data back to the backend. So how do I make it render iframes on first init?

Answer (score 0):

Is it posible, but if you want use iframe that mean you want render a page there ? check this plugin [oEmbed](http://ckeditor.com/addon/oembed). This plugin render a Iframe with a youtoube or other media sites/video.